# An Extended component styled-component doesn't make onClick emit

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

### Expected Behavior

Submitting the form when I click on a button which extends style imported from another styled-component.

### Problem

Although the extended component is applied style to decorate more style, this component doesn't make `onClick` work well.

```
class User_Edit_Form extends Component {
  
    return (
      <>
        <FormArea>
          
        //   Omitted    //

          <TextLiTag>
            <SubmitButton
              btn_type="submit"
              btn_click={this.handleSubmit}
              btn_disable={!info.username || !info.email || message.username || message.email}
            >Submit
            </SubmitButton>
          </TextLiTag>
        </FormArea>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

And `SubmitButton` comes from this component.

```
function MiddleButton(props) {
  return (
    <StyledButton
      className={props.className}
      type={props.btn_type}
      onClick={props.btn_click}
      onSubmit={props.btn_submit}
      disabled={props.btn_disable}
    >
      {props.children}
    </StyledButton>
  );
}

export default MiddleButton;

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  height: 45px;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 1.18em;
  font-weight: 550;
  padding: 2px 3.5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
`;

export const SubmitButton = styled(StyledButton)`
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: ${(props) => !props.btn_disable ? '#8DD6FF' : '#E0F4FF'};
  color: ${(props) => !props.btn_disable ?  '#466A80' : '#BDCFDA' };
  box-shadow: 4px 3px ${Colors.accent1};

  &:hover:enabled{
    background-color:#A8E0FF;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
  }

  &:active:enabled{
    box-shadow:0px 0px 0px;
    transform: translate(4px, 3px);
  }
`;
```

This is the codes has the problem.
When I see what `props` this component has with `Chrome dev tool`, it has other `props` like `btn_type`.
I am really getting stuck here. I tried all solutions I came up with and found.

If it is alright with you, I would like you to teach me how to figure it out.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example, how `this.handleSubmit` looks like? Dont show code parts, better make a codesandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-t80qj

Comment: @DennisVash Thank you for your comment. I created a new sandbox and copy a link to it. When you are free, would you please check this? This is the link => https://codesandbox.io/s/great-cohen-2nnbo?file=/Form.jsx

Comment: Please make a minimal example to reproduce the problem, you shared a code with thousands of lines

Comment: And your code doesnt even running, you just copied it